# An ethereum token standard for minting and burning only

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin

Does there exist a token standard (ERC or EIP) that has an interface similar to below?

```
interface token {
    function totalSupply() external view;
    function mint(address _account, address _amount) external;
    function burn(address _account, address _amount) external;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the closest is the IERC20:

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20

Hope it helps